# Proving foot of altitude and intersection of circle centered at defined points and sides are collinear

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

A friend sent me this geometry proof problem:

> Let $H$ be the orthocenter of acute $\triangle ABC.$ Points $D$ and $M$ are defined as the projection of $A$ onto segment $BC$ and the midpoint of segment $BC,$ respectively. Let $H'$ be the reflection of orthocenter $H$ over the midpoint of $DM,$ and construct a circle $\Gamma$ centered at $H'$ passing through $B$ and $C.$ Given that $\Gamma$ intersects lines $AB$ and $AC$ at points $X \neq B$ and $Y \neq C$ respectively, show that points $X,D,Y$ lie on a line.

Here is my attempt: It suffices to show $P,$ the point of intersection of diagonals of cyclic quadrilateral $BYCX,$ is $D.$ Thus it suffices to show $\angle HPB = \angle HPM = 90^\circ.$

Let $\angle A = \alpha, \angle B = \beta, \angle C = \gamma.$ Note $\angle YBX=180^\circ-\beta$ and $\angle C = \angle YXB=\gamma.$ Therefore, $\angle BPX = \beta - \gamma.$ Note then $\angle CPX = 180^\circ-(\beta-\gamma).$ Angles in a triangle add to $180^\circ,$ so $\angle PCX + \angle CXP= \beta-\gamma.$ So $\angle YXC + \angle YCX =\beta.$ Therefore $\angle XYC = 180^\circ - \beta.$ Thus $\angle AYX=\beta.$ Thus $\angle BPY = 360^\circ-\alpha-2\beta.$

However, even with all these angle relations, it does not seem to be any use to show $\angle HPB = \angle HPM = 90^\circ.$ I have also tried coordinate-bashing, which turned out terribly (I do not suggest anyone to try this as if done my way, it would involve the coordinate of an orthocenter formula, leading to very disgusting and hard to simplify expressions and equations). May I have some help? Am I going in the right direction, or does this lead to a dead end? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$\angle BXY=\angle BCY$

So:

$\triangle PYC\sim\triangle PBX$

So we have:

$\frac{BP}{PY}=\frac{XP}{PC}$

Or:

$BP\times PC=XP\times PY$

Now draw circle L centered on midpoint of BC, so it passes B and C(BC is it's diameter). It intersect Altitude AD at Q. Draw another circle S diameter as XY(centered on midpoint of XY).Draw third circle T centered on D with radius QD, it intersect circle S at point R. In right angle triangle QBC we have:

$QD^2=BD\times DC$

In right angled triangle XRY we have:

$XD\times DY= RD^2$

So we have:

$RD^2=QD^2$

$\Rightarrow  BD\times DC=XD\times DY$

That means $\triangle BDX \sim \triangle DYC$

Since YC and BX are also sides of triangle YPC and BPX, this give the result that P is coincident on D or point X, D and Y are on one line.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! I will take a look at your hints first and will ask any questions I have about your solution if I have any.